# Sample C code for Azure IOT Central device

Tags: azure-iot-central

I'm trying to develop a device suing Azure SDK C. I'm able to send telemetry messages (using the "iothub_ll_telemetry_sample" sample) but I'm NOT able to receive settings (I define a setting, FanSpeed, but when I change the value on IOT Central then I don't receive any callbacks).
There is it a working sample? possibly for Windows.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Azure iot central firmware examples on github. I would suggest you to look at [AZ3166 example for azure iot central](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/tree/master/AZ3166)

Answer (score 0):

For Azure IOT Central I have found the most useful examples to be located on the Azure IOT Central firmware github:
https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware

The repository has been reorganized a bit since the earlier answer from Ozzz. You can find a C code example in the [MXChip example](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware/tree/master/MXCHIP).